# Como abrir outra viewControler no Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Pessoal sou novo em programação swift e estou com uma duvida. Tenho dois arquivos
O principal: ViewController.swift e um outro que eu criei chamado ViewSegundo.swift.

Fiz a classe

```
import UIKit

class ViewSegundo: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var img4: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


    }
}
```

apontei ela no custom class da segunda View, quando utilizo o botão direito do mouse sobre o botão e seto para segunda view funciona, mais eu preciso fazer via código, e não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um novo controller você precisa escrever assim dentro do evento do click de um button:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegundaViewController", sender:self)
```

Você pode fazer também na forma visual, que seria arrastando o button até a view e selecionando `push`

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, agora sim com sua dica vi que alem do código precisava identificar o storyboard segue com o nome da segunda View ai eu puxei da View principal a ligação para outra view Secundaria dei o nome e utilizei o o código e deu tudo certo.

Comment: @user1649307 se deu certo marque a respota como aceita, para que as pessoas possam identificar que a resposta resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: Que tal fazer um tour pelo `SO` ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour